# Python class using base method loses type

Tags: python, class, inheritance

```
class test(list):
   def dummy_method(self):
      pass

a=test()
b=test()

type(a)
```

Returns test.

```
type(a+b)
```

Returns list. I wanted test.

Obviously I could create a new `__add__` (and `__radd__` I guess) method which wraps the base method and returns something with the right class but it doesn't seem very elegant...

Comment: Yet that's what you have to do; the `list` type is optimised for speed, not for subclassing. You can also base of the `UserList` class or the `Sequence` ABC; Python 3 has those in `collections` and `collections.abc` respectively, Python 2 in `UserList` and `collections`.